# wordpress fotobook plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded the fotobook plugin from [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fotobook/). The images are uploaded through facebook only.  Is it possible to upload image directly and preview doesn't works properly online.

Please see [this](http://www.aaronharp.com/photo-gallery/) location.

If I click the photos a blank transparent screen appears and image didn't display. How to get it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You use the last version of wordpress and the plugin was created more than a year ago. And there is no information about their compatibility on this page. I didn't try this plugin but I had the similar problem with old wordpress themes.